# Why alg(v) is not normclosed in the Banach algebra V in general?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let V be an unital Banach algebra, v $\in V$. The smallest subalgebra of V, with contains v and e, is defined as follows:

$\overline{alg(v)}:=\overline{\{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\lambda_kv^k: \lambda_k\in\mathbb{C}, n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\}}.$

My question is: Why is it necessary to take the closure of alg(v) to get the completeness of alg(v) / Why alg(v) is not normclosed in V in general?

I know that a closed subspace of a Banach space is itself a Banach space. But in alg(v) are contained finite sums in v with complexe coefficients...I don't see the problem.. Regards

Comment: In general, the (algebraic) dimension of $\operatorname{alg}(v)$ is countably infinite. Do you know Baire's theorem?

Comment: Ok. I need the closure of alg(v) only if V is infinite dimensional? Why is alg(v) in general countable? I thought, that alg(v) is uncountable because the coefficients of the polynomials are in $\mathbb{C}$. I know Baire's theorem in the following version: Let (T,d) a complete metric space and $(O_n)_n$ a sequence of open, dense subsets in T. Then $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty O_n$ is dense. Edit: Ok, now I have found a question of MSE "Let X be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every basis of X is uncountable.".

Comment: If $\operatorname{alg}(v)$ is finite-dimensional, it is automatically closed, so then one would not need to take the closure. $\operatorname{alg}(v)$ is not countable; it has countable dimension. If you take complements in your version of Baire's theorem, you get that a complete metric space is not the union of countably many nowhere dense closed subsets. But a vector space of countable dimension is the union of countably many finite-dimensional subspaces. If the space is normed, finite-dimensional subspaces are closed and nowhere dense.

Comment: Ok, the question " I need the closure of alg(v) only if V is infinite dimensional?" is clear.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok thank you:)!. I needed time to think about it, but now i understand it.